# How to simultaneously change keyboard layouts and text direction in Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: keyboard, windows, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Currently, my system is set up with English and Arabic, two languages with opposing text directions. In Windows, upon pressing Alt-Shift (the default shortcut to change scripts), not only does script change, but so does the text direction in anticipation of an opposing one, making for nice and tidy visuals. I would like the same in Ubuntu.

**Is it possible to change both the script (like from English to Arabic) and text direction (LTR to RTL) at the same time, and if so, how?**

Comment: Have you installed language support for Arabic in Ubuntu? Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Which Arabic keyboard layout did you install and write the exact steps for installation. [Edit your question and add all these information](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1439289/edit).

Comment: The text direction in the input window is instantly changed, isn't it? Please clarify.

Comment: You may have to install the Arabic language support in **System Settings > Region & Languages > Manage Installed Languages > Install / Remove Languages...**. This is in addition to adding Arabic keyboard layout under **System Settings > Keyboard > Input Sources**.